# Travel Schengen countries while applying for UK visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, passports, indonesian-citizens

I am a foreign student at Sweden. Indonesian passport holder. I have Swedish ID Card and also the residence permit. Right now, I am applying for UK Visa. I submitted my passport and my residence permit card to be sent to UK for this purpose just yesterday. The problem is, I am also planning to have a trip around the Schengen countries next week. I already booked tickets throughout my itinerary.

Is it possible for me to do this trip around Schengen countries without my passport?

Or...

Is there any way I could get some sort of letter from UK immigration office which tells that my passport is indeed currently hold by them? Can I use such letter as temporary replacement for my passport?

Comment: It should be back before then

Comment: I don't think you'll have problems if you have the residency card.